# How to find all words in a string in R?

Tags: r

I want to find all the words in a character vector, but I want to assume that words can be separated by punctuation characters too, not just empty spaces.

I can always do something like `s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]`, to get all the words separated by empty space, but what if they are separated by other punctuation marks, and the user has simply forgotten to include blank spaces?

I believe I need to write some kind of regular expression to match only the words, and ignore the punctuation.

**EDIT:**

I simply want to split my string to words. If I have something like `I,love pizza-because/it tastes.good`, I want to get all the words, meaning `"I", "love", "pizza", "because", "it", "tastes", "good"`. As I told you if the words are separated just by empty spaces it is easy, but what if they are separated by different punctuation symbols?

I mean I can always use something like `str_replace_all(x, "[[:punct:]]", " ")`, and then separate them by empty space, but I don't want to rely on some external package, nor destroy the original strings form.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the solution you expect.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll Check edit please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option with `:punct:`:

```
> strsplit("I,love pizza-because/it tastes.good", "[[:punct:] ]")
[[1]]
[1] "I"       "love"    "pizza"   "because" "it"      "tastes"  "good"
```

Comment: This fails to split at spaces. Try it with the lorem ipsum text.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll It works, space is included in the character class.

Comment: `x <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, omnes inermis inimicus his an. Impedit phaedrum torquatos vix ea. Pro ex atqui novum sonet, ut odio graece ridens vel. Elitr bonorum in sea."` ... `strsplit(x, "[[:punct:]]")` ... `[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"          " omnes inermis inimicus his an" `

Comment: @JonathanCarroll You forgot to include the space in the character class. The answer has it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ah, I missed that, which I guess goes to show that it's a less transparent option than \\W. It fails at newline characters though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the POSIX class `[[:punct:]]` or `\\w` for word characters.  The R regex page discusses the character classes.

```
tst <- "I,love pizza-because/it tastes.good"
regmatches(tst, gregexpr("\\w+", tst))
```

Answer (score 2):

Splitting on a negated word (`\\W`) should do the trick.

```
x <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, omnes inermis inimicus his an. Impedit
phaedrum torquatos vix ea. Pro ex atqui novum sonet, ut odio graece ridens
vel. Elitr bonorum in sea."

strsplit(x, "\\W")

[[1]]
 [1] "Lorem"           "ipsum"           "dolor"           "sit"             "amet"           
 [6] ""                "omnes"           "inermis"         "inimicus"        "his"            
[11] "an"              ""                "Impedit"         "phaedrum"        "torquatos" 

y <- "I,love pizza-because/it tastes.good"

strsplit(y, "\\W")

[[1]]
[1] "I"       "love"    "pizza"   "because" "it"      "tastes"  "good"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the \W meaning non-word character:

```
> strsplit("I,love pizza-because/it tastes.good","\\W")
[[1]]
[1] "I"       "love"    "pizza"   "because" "it"      "tastes"  "good"   

> strsplit("I,love pizza-because/it,, tastes.good","\\W")
[[1]]
[1] "I"       "love"    "pizza"   "because" "it"      ""        ""        "tastes"  "good"   

> strsplit("I,love pizza-because/it,, tastes.good","\\W+")
[[1]]
[1] "I"       "love"    "pizza"   "because" "it"      "tastes"  "good"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `stri_extract_all` from `library(stringi)`.  It is already commented, but not in the solution format.

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(tst, "\\w+")[[1]]
#[1] "I"       "love"    "pizza"   "because" "it"      "tastes"  "good"
```

---

Or we can use `gsub` from `base R` to replace all the punct characters to a single delimiter and then `scan` the string.

```
scan(text=gsub("[[:punct:]]", ",", tst), what="", 
                 sep=",", quiet=TRUE)
#[1] "I"          "love pizza" "because"    "it tastes"  "good"
```

#### data

```
tst <- "I,love pizza-because/it tastes.good"
```